# why does my number comparing alway become true?

Tags: batch-file

Whenever I run the script, even when the time is under 12:03 it always runs as if the time was over 12:03, And I don't understand why. I wanted to compare the time of day to a set time for an automatic shutdown, but it always returns the time as over my set clock, even when it isn't.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
timeout /t 30
:RunAgain
set HH=12
set MM=03

set ThisHour=%TIME:~0,2%
set ThisMinute=%TIME:~3,2%

echo time: %ThisHour%:%ThisMinute%

if ThisHour GEQ HH (
    echo Hour is over %HH%
    if ThisMinute GEQ MM (
        goto Shutdown
        
    ) ELSE (
        echo time is under %HH%:%MM%
        timeout /t 30
        goto RunAgain )
) ELSE (
    echo time is under %HH%:%MM%
    timeout /t 30
    goto RunAgain )

:Shutdown
echo Shutting down
pause
```

Comment: You can shutdown the computer at a specific time using using the Windows Task Scheduler. There is no need to create a script which runs constantly, looping until a specific time has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the variables are not being correctly passed to the **IF** statement.

When passing them to the **IF**, you should add `%` around the variable names.

It is recommended to use `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe` instead of just `timeout` to avoid that the `cmd.exe` process has to make multiple file system accesses to find this executable.

You can change the script to:

```
@echo off
set HH=12
set MM=03

:RunAgain
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /t 30
set ThisHour=%TIME:~0,2%
set ThisMinute=%TIME:~3,2%

echo time: %ThisHour%:%ThisMinute%

if "%ThisHour%" GTR "%HH%" echo Hour is over %HH%& goto Shutdown
if "%ThisHour%" == "%HH%" if "%ThisMinute%" GEQ "%MM%" echo Hour is over %HH%& goto Shutdown
echo time is under %HH%:%MM%& goto RunAgain

:Shutdown
echo Shutting down
pause
```

After doing these changes, the script works as intended.

Script output for under 12:

```
Waiting for 29 seconds, press a key to continue ...
time: 10:12
time is under 12:03

Waiting for 22 seconds, press a key to continue ...
```

Script output for over 12:

```
Waiting for 28 seconds, press a key to continue ...
time: 22:14
Hour is over 12
Shutting down
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for the comments and corrections :)

Comment: Try `set /a MM=09` to see another reason you shouldn't use `set /a` in this case.

Comment: Done with the modifications, thanks for the links and useful information provided!